# Habilitar un boton cuando todos los campos requeridos esten llenos

Tags: jsf, java-ee

No tengo mucha experiencia en **front-end** y he estado realizando un simple formulario de login, en este formulario el botón de enviar (submit) se carga con `disable = true` (de acuerdo a los atributos del botón) y se debe habilitar solo cuando los campos de usuario y contraseña se hayan ingresado (que no sean vacíos o null).

El formulario que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<form jsf:id="loginForm" autocomplete="off">
    <div>
        <label jsf:for="username">User name</label>
        <h:inputText id="userName" value="#{bean.userName}">
            <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="summit"/>
        </h:inputText>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label jsf:for="password">Password</label>
        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{bean.password}">
            <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="summit"/>
        </h:inputSecret>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h:commandButton id="summit" type="submit" value="Signin" action="#{bean.session}" disabled="#{empty bean.userName or empty bean.password}" >
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:commandButton type="reset" value="Borrar" />
    </div>
</form>
```

En el **commanButton** el atributo disabled tiene la condición para habilitar o deshabilitar, esto funciona bien si uso un solo atributo (usuario o contraseña) o cuando uso el operador `'and'`, pero cuando uso el operador `'or'`no funciona el botón nunca se habilita.

Answer (score 0):

en el commandbutton submit podrias utilizar el atributo rendered en lugar de disabled del siguiente modo:

```
<h:commandButton id="summit" rendered="#{bean.usernName and bean.password}">
```

Este codigo funciona, lo acabo de probar

```
<h:form id="componentes">
          <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:inputText id="userName" value="#{wordController.usuario}">
              <f:ajax render="summit" execute="@form"/>
            </h:inputText>
            <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{wordController.password}">
              <f:ajax  render="summit" execute="@form"/>
            </h:inputSecret>
            <h:commandButton id="summit" type="submit" value="Signin"
                             disabled="#{empty wordController.usuario or empty wordController.password}" >
              <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form"/>
            </h:commandButton>
          </h:panelGrid>
```

solo reemplaza wordController por bean

Edicion 2, le agregue el evento keyup para que detecte las pulsaciones

```
<h:inputText id="userName" value="#{wordController.usuario}">
          <f:ajax render="summit" execute="@form" event="keyup"/>
        </h:inputText>
        <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{wordController.password}">
          <f:ajax  render="summit" execute="@form" event="keyup"/>
        </h:inputSecret>
```

Comment: No, no funcionno, adicional el atributo `rendered`, es para visualización, cuando la pagina se carga los campos UnserName y password estan vacios lo cual deberia hacer que el botón no se visualizara al cargar la pagina, pero si se visualiza.